# Function to update object values with different nesting depths

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This may be a duplicate as I believe it's a common situation but I can't find anything on Stack Overflow that answers my question.

I have set an object that holds my initial state as follows (extract to show only relevant values for this question):

```
export const initialState = {
  signUpDialog: {
    open: false,
    nameField: {
      isEmpty: false,
      isInvalid: false
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `open` state is nested 1 deep under signUpDialog however `isEmpty` and `isInvalid` are nested 2 deep.

I am using React Hooks to manage state, and have the following action creator to pass values to my state reducer:

```
export const TOGGLE_BOOLEAN = "TOGGLE_BOOLEAN";
export function toggleBoolean(state, subState, value) {
  return {
    type: TOGGLE_BOOLEAN,
    payload: {
      state: state,
      subState: subState,
      value: value
    }
  };
}
```

And the following reducer that changes the state (note: the `state` param is equal to the current state and the `action` param is equal to the return value of the `toggleBoolean` action creator):

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  const reduced = { ...state };
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_BOOLEAN:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        ...reduced,
        [action.payload.state]: {
          ...reduced[action.payload.state],
          [action.payload.subState]: action.payload.value
        }
      });
    default:
      state;
  }
};
```

This works fine for updating the `open` state as it's only nested 1 deep under action.payload.state='signUpForm', however it won't work for `name: { isEmpty}` or `name: { isInvalid }` as those are both nested 2 deep.

I know I could solve this by having different action creators and switch cases for each level of depth, however it wouldn't be DRY as they are essentially doing the same thing.

Are there any simpler DRY solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple code sketch. Maybe it will help you find a solution -

```js
const setKV = (k, v) => (o = {}) =>
  ({ ...o, [k]: v })

const setDeepKV = (k, v, ...more) => (o = {}) =>
  more.length === 0
    ? setKV (k, v) (o)
    : setKV (k, setDeepKV (v, ...more) (o [k])) (o)

const print = (...vs) =>
  vs .forEach (v => console.log (v))

print
  ( setDeepKV ('a', 'X') ({})
  // { a: 'X' }
  
  , setDeepKV ('a', 'X') ({ a: 1, b: 2 })
  // { a: 'X', b: 2 }

  , setDeepKV ('a', 'a1', 'a2', 'X') ({ a: 1, b: 2 })
  // { a: { a1: { a2: 'X' } }, b: 2 }

  , setDeepKV ('a', 'b', 'c', 'X') ({ a: { b: { c: 1, d: 2 } }, e: 3 })
  // { a: { b: { c: 'X', d: 2 } }, e: 3 }

  , setDeepKV ('a', 'b', 'X') ({ a: { b: { c: 1, d: 2 } }, e: 3 })
  // { a: { b: 'X' }, e: 3 }
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working use this as an example. I'll edit my post to include my solution.